# StompJS Timeout on watchForReceipt() method

Tags: javascript, websocket, livechat, stompjs

I've built a livechat application using StompJS on the client. I'm using `client.waitForReceipt()` to confirm broker consumption but I want to add a timeout on it so if they fail, it doesn't wait forever. Is there a way to set a timeout on this or programmatically stop waiting for a receipt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.waitForReceipt()` is deprecated.